# How to modify my PHP database extraction class to work with MySQLi

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am getting a warning stating:

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

It has been a while since I worked with PHP which leads me to struggle figuring out why the size function in the MySQLReturn class is giving me grief. It is an old class I used years ago and modified it as best I could to work with `php7` and `MySQLi`.

```
    <?php

class MySQL {

private $host;
private $dbUser;
private $dbPass;
private $dbName;
private $dbConn;
private $connectError;

public function __construct($host,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbName) {
    $this->host=$host;
    $this->dbUser=$dbUser;
    $this->dbPass=$dbPass;
    $this->dbName=$dbName;
    $this->connectToDb();
}

public function __destruct() {
}

public function connectToDb () {
    // Make connection to MySQL server
    if (!$this->dbConn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->dbUser,$this->dbPass)) {
        trigger_error('Could not connect to server');
        $this->connectError=true;
    // Select database
    } else if (!mysqli_select_db($this->dbConn,$this->dbName)) {
        trigger_error('Could not select database');
        $this->connectError=true;
    }
}

public function isError () {
    if ($this->connectError)
        return true;
    $error=mysqli_error($this->dbConn);
    if (empty($error))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


public function query($sql) {
 if (!$queryResource=mysqli_query($this->dbConn,$sql)) trigger_error ('Query failed: '.mysqli_error($this->dbConn).' SQL: '.$sql);
        $result = new MySQLReturn($this,$queryResource);
        return $result;
}
}

class MySQLReturn {

private $mysql;

private $query;

public function MySQLResult($mysql,$query) {
    $this->mysql=$mysql;
    $this->query=$query;
}

public function fetch() {
    if ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($this->query,MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
        return $row;
    } else if ( $this->size() > 0 ) {
        mysqli_data_seek($this->query,0);
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function size() {
    return mysqli_num_rows($this->query);
}

public function insertID() {
    return mysqli_insert_id($this->mysql->dbConn);
}

public function isError() {
    return $this->mysql->isError();
}
}
?>
```

This is how I am accessing the class functions;

```
    <?php
$db = new MySQL($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbmain);
$authsql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$uid."' AND password=MD5('".$pwd."')");

if ($authsql->size() >= '1') {
$logindtsql = $db->query("UPDATE users SET last_login=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE email='".$uid."' AND password=MD5('".$pwd."')");
$authsqlrow = $authsql->fetch();
extract($authsqlrow);
}

if ($authsql->size() == 0) {
   unset($_SESSION['uid']);
   unset($_SESSION['pwd']);
   session_destroy();
}
?>
```

I am not getting the size of the query

Comment: Have you done any debugging such as dumping what `$this->query` actually is when it gets passed to `mysqli_num_rows()`?

Comment: Also enable error reporting.

Comment: Error reporting is enabled and that warning is the only message I get. I am only getting a warning however I am not getting the number of rows out of the query I am looking for.

Comment: What's the actual stack trace?  Is the warning thrown by `$authsqlrow = $authsql->fetch();` or by `if ($authsql->size() == 0)`?  Still curious if you've done any basic debugging.

Comment: It is thrown by "if ($authsql->size() == 0)". As mentioned in my OP it has been a while since I worked with PHP. How do I dump $this->query?

Comment: [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). Also check to see if you're getting inside your `if ($authsql->size() >= '1') {` block with something like `echo 'INSIDE FIRST IF';`

Comment: It is returning a 0 value. var_dump (return var_dump($this->query);) inside the size function is returning null null.

Comment: BTW your help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
public function MySQLResult($mysql,$query) {
    $this->mysql=$mysql;
    $this->query=$query;
}
```

to

```
public function __construct($mysql,$query) {
    $this->mysql=$mysql;
    $this->query=$query;
}
```

Works like a charm